# How to clear text to speech queue?

Tags: android

```
    public void talk(String en, final String tr, final UtteranceProgressListener listener) {

    tts_en.speak(en, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null,en);
    tts_tr.speak(tr, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null,tr);

    tts_tr.setOnUtteranceProgressListener(new UtteranceProgressListener() {
        @Override
        public void onStart(String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onDone(String s) {

            listener.onDone(s);

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(String s) {

        }
    });

}
```

I call the above method in a while loop.The problem is, lags start after 1 hour when tts is speaking.I want to clear tts queue when the list is back to the start.How can i do it?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of passing QUEUE_ADD, pass QUEUE_FLUSH if you want to clear the queue.

```
tts_tr.speak(tr, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null,tr);
```

Comment: I tried this before.If i do as you say the sounds overtaking.

Comment: QUEUE_FLUSH will drop the current playback queue and replace it by new entry

Comment: can you please add more code here, where you are calling talk function.